# How can i integrate/sync/link/connect SHAREPOINT to TFS(Visual studio) and vice versa

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, tfs, integrate

i need help on how to integrate sharepoint with tfs

Senario:
when i change the task info in sharepoint, i want it to automatically update in tfs and vice-versa.

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to have some sort of third party synchronisation tool. I would look at TaskTop in the first instance and then OpsHub is you really have to and have deep pockets. If you want a non-robust option then you could cut a little code to listen to both SharePoint and TFS events to update. There is a POC adapter for the TFS Integration Tools that syncs a SharePoint document list with the TFS Source Repo. It could get you started...